# how to discriminate text from numeric and missing values in R?

Tags: r, text, replace

I have a variable in the dataset contains three types of values: text(string), numeric, and missing values. All of them are stored as a factor now. I want to distinguish the text content from the numeric values and the missing values. How could I get it?

```
Data <- data.frame(x=c("100","20","home","","30"))
```

there are three type of values here, number, text, and missing values, I want to find the locations of all text

Comment: Use `is.numeric` and `is.na`?  But you should show this data to us.

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: it will only give the data which are strings or missing values, so I cannot distinguish missing values and strings. I will show you my data later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract text, numeric and missing indices separately with regex:

```
grep("[:alpha:]+", Data$x)
# [1] 3

grep("[0-9]+", Data$x)
# [1] 1 2 5

grep("^\\s*$", Data$x)
# [1] 4
```

To get the actual values, use `value=TRUE`:

```
grep("[:alpha:]+", Data$x, value = TRUE)
# [1] "home"

grep("[0-9]+", Data$x, value = TRUE)
# [1] "100" "20"  "30"

grep("^\\s*$", Data$x, value = TRUE)
# [1] ""
```

`[:alpha:]+` matches any alphabet *one or more times*

`[0-9]+` matches any numbers *one or more times*

`^` matches start of string, `$` matches end of string, and `\\s*` matches spaces *zero or more times*, so `^\\s*$` matches *only* spaces *zero or more times*.